# One page navigation with the JQuery magic line menu

Tags: jquery, navigation

I have made a one page site where my content is divided into boxes. I am using the Magic Line Menu to navigate quickly between the boxes. Now I am tying to figure out how to change the current page item in my menu when I scroll between the boxes manually. 
This is what I am trying to implement in the magic line script.

```
// Bind to scroll
$(window).scroll(function(){
   // Get container scroll position
   var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop()+topMenuHeight;

   // Get id of current scroll item
   var cur = scrollItems.map(function(){
     if ($(this).offset().top < fromTop)
       return this;
   });
   // Get the id of the current element
   cur = cur[cur.length-1];
   var id = cur && cur.length ? cur[0].id : "";

   if (lastId !== id) {
       lastId = id;
       // Set/remove active class
       menuItems
         .parent().removeClass("active")
         .end().filter("[href=#"+id+"]").parent().addClass("active");
   }                   
});
```

I put together a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vtuKH/77/) of how i navigate on my page.

And this is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/up4nu/) of how the the menue is updated when the page is scrolled.

Help is much appreciated ! Thank you.

Comment: If there a reason you want to use MagicLine than what is provided in the ScrollSpy fiddle?

Comment: Yes, I realy love the way how the line of the Menu adapts to the size of the different Menu items and how it follows the cursor. I am realy new to Javascript and can't figure it out how get current page items to update in the Magic line menu whilst scrolling the Page.